# Google maps marker not showing up javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I'm trying to add a marker to my google map within my HTML project. The map centres on the exact coordinates I like and is perfect except the marker I've added doesn't show up at all. I've followed the documentation but to no success.

```
var google;

function init() {

var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.69847032728747, -73.9514422416687);

var mapOptions = {
    // How zoomed in you want the map to start at (always required)
    zoom: 7,

    // The latitude and longitude to center the map (always required)
    center: myLatlng,

    // How you would like to style the map. 
    scrollwheel: false,
    styles: [
        {
            "featureType": "administrative.country",
            "elementType": "geometry",
            "stylers": [
                {
                    "visibility": "simplified"
                },
                {
                    "hue": "#ff0000"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

I'm using a div with id="map" seen below

```
var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');

var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);

var addresses = ['New York'];

for (var x = 0; x < addresses.length; x++) {
    $.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+addresses[x]+'&sensor=false', null, function (data) {
        var p = data.results[0].geometry.location
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);
        new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            title: 'NY'
        });

    });
}

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
```

Comment: *I've followed the documentation but to no success.* - I don't believe you... the documentation is full of examples on how to properly use their APIs and all examples include an API key. You should also mention in your question what you have tried to debug. Did you open your browser's javascript console? What's in there?

Comment: What errors do you get in the console? (I get `You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional information, please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account`). PS - you shouldn't use the web service geocoding API from javascript, it doesn't work, use the Geocoder in the Google Maps Javascript API v3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add your API key.

`$.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+addresses[x]+'&sensor=false&key=ADD_YOUR_API_KEY', null, function (data) {`

Check this out!

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#GeocodingResponses